# Populate JList with threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I want JList to be populated with multiple threads.
I tried this way but jlist is empty. 
It would be good if jlist was updated on the fly
There are two threads, the other one loads in anouther direction

```
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(i=0; i<cells.size()/2; i++){
                    System.out.println("thread");

                    try{
                        HtmlPage p = client.getPage("https://tbilisi.embassytools.com/en/slotsReserve?slot="+cells.get(i).getAttribute("data-slotid"));
                        pages.add(p);
                        if(!p.getUrl().toString().contains("slotsReserve"))
                            model.add(i,p.getUrl().toString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
list1.setModel(model)
```

Thanks in advance

*UPDATE******
So I fixed by using SwingWorker

Comment: You don't `start()` your threads. And you shouldn't do it that way, as Swing is not threadsafe. Read about "SwingWorker"

Answer (score 1):

Swing is a single threaded framework, that is, it is expected that all updates and modifications to the UI are done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Equally, you should do nothing in the EDT that might block or otherwise prevent it from processing the Event Queue (like downloading content from the web).

This raise a conundrum.  Can't update the UI outside the EDT, need to use some kind of background process to execute time consuming/blocking tasks...

So long as the order of items is unimportant, you would use multiple `SwingWorker`s in place o of the `Thread`s, for example...

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

/*...*/

LoadWorker worker = new LoadWorker(model);
worker.execute();    

/*...*/

public class LoaderWorker extends SwingWorker<List<URL>, String> {

    private DefaultListModel model;

    public LoaderWorker(DefaultListModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    protected void process(List<String> pages) {
        for (String page : pages) {
            model.add(page);
        }
    }

    protected List<URL> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>(25);
        for(i=0; i<cells.size()/2; i++){
            try{
                HtmlPage p = client.getPage("https://tbilisi.embassytools.com/en/slotsReserve?slot="+cells.get(i).getAttribute("data-slotid"));
                pages.add(p);
                if(!p.getUrl().toString().contains("slotsReserve")) {
                    publish(p.getUrl().toString());
                    urls.add(p.getUrl());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }        
        }
        return urls;
    }
}
```

This allows you execute your blocking/long running in the backround (`doInBackground`) and `publish` the results of this method which are then `process`ed within the context of the EDT...

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Swing is [not thread safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) you **should** use SwingUtilities to run multiple threads updating swing.

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      doWhateverYouWant();
    }
});
```

[read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)